# Making numbered lists in reStructuredText

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How can I make a numbered list in reStructuredText where each item is a link to some corresponding text below? For example for use in an "FAQ" page, where the questions are listed and numbered as hyperlinks and each question's link leads to its answer below on the page. For example:

```
1. question 1 [links to #1 below]
2. question 2 [links to #2 below]
3. question 3 [links to #3 below]
4. ...

#1 question 1:
the answer to question 1

#2 question 2:
the answer to question 2

#3 question 3:
the answer to question 3
```

In HTML this can be done with `hrefs` and the `#` symbol, but I'm wondering what is the equivalent reStructuredText syntax?

Comment: Is [this](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents) the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Doesn't look like it unless I'm missing something.. I already have a TOC in my document and I want one of the sections to have this kind of hyperlinked list... very trivial, just numbered items that link to a corresponding section below. Do I need to make each item in the list a section and have a second TOC in the document? Is that what you are proposing? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [enumerated lists](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#enumerated-lists) and [internal hyperlink targets](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#internal-hyperlink-targets) in the first Google result for "restructuredtext list". You can combine these like so:

```
#. `question 1`_
#. `question 2`_

.. _question 1:
the answer to question 1
```

For backreferences per your comment, you can use "[inline internal targets](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#inline-internal-targets)", which the quick reference mentions but only the full reference actually describes. Unfortunately, it seems to be impossible for the same text to be both a link and a target (even if the syntax technically allowed it, it would be ambiguous), so you would need more text in the list item than just the question. Your best way might be to have each question link back to the *list* rather than to a particular list item - eg,

```
.. _List of questions:
...

.. _question 1:
the answer to question 1
`List of questions`_
```

Comment: I think that needs to be `.. _question 1:` to work. But still, the numbering is not automatic here... you need to type question 1, 2 etc when defining the answer so this is not an automatic solution, the user still has to keep track of the order of the questions and the answers are not backreferenced to the questions.

Comment: @user248237 I've added the `_`, good catch. In your question you ask for something like HTML internal hrefs - but they have exactly the same problem you describe. You need to keep track of the pairings between `href` and `target` manually.

Comment: you're right. so let's say I keep the pairing manually.. how can I backreference them so that I have a link that says "go back to question 1" in the numbered list from the answer to question 1? also, can I put markup inside the reference? this does not seem to work: ``question 1 has ``code`` in it``_

Comment: I don't understand the whitespace in restructured... sometimes it puts the "id" tag in the HTML if I have `.. _question 1` and if i have several of those, it drops them... very strange. makes no sense.

Comment: @user248237 the `.. _question 1` is a link *target*, and so having multiple of them is ambiguous - see http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#implicit-hyperlink-targets for the rules on how rst resolves that. The "implicit targets" that it mentions could also be useful - if  answers all have the questions immediately above as headings, then you can use those as link targets without needing `.. _question 1` at all. I'm not sure why it would only sometimes put `id` in the HTML - AIUI that's the accepted way to do link targets now, with `name` being reserved for forms.

Answer (score 5):

A good example to start with is the [Docutils FAQ](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html) (reStructuredText was developed along side Docutils and Sphinx is simply an extension of Docutils). Here the FAQ is constructed simply with section headings and the [table of contents directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents) (see the reStructuredText source, link at the bottom of the page).

You say in a comment that you already have a table of contents on your page, so want you want is a second table of contents which is local to the FAQ section. This can be done with the `:local:` option to the `contents` directive. Try out the following example to see this local table of contents in action:

```
=======================================
Testing the inclusion of an FAQ section
=======================================

.. contents:: Table of Contents
   :depth: 1

Some uninteresting section
==========================

with some text...

FAQ
===

.. contents::
  :local:
  :backlinks: none
  :depth: 1

Question 1
----------

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

Question 2
----------

Suspendisse tortor tellus...

Question 3
----------

Mauris in magna sed arcu semper auctor vitae eu risus...

Some other uninteresting section
================================

with some text...
```